# How do I apply an edited actionscript class to an MXML component in Flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, mxml

I was wondering how I apply an edited actionscript class to a component??

I've made a few changes to the TileLayout class (spark.layout.supportClasses.LayoutBase), but am unable to apply this new layout format to my group in my application... is it treated like a different tag within the layout tag?

eg

`<s:layout> <s:TileLayout horizontalAlign="justify" /> </s:layout>`

to

`<s:layout> <s:MyNewLayoutClass horizontalAlign="justify" /> </s:layout>`

Thanks a lot in advance, I really appreciate the answers this community provides!

Josh

Comment: Does MyNewLayoutClass derive from LayoutBase at any point in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it treated like a different tag
>   within the layout tag?

Yes, but instead of `<s:MyNewLayoutClass .../>`, where the **s** references the spark namespace, you would use your own custom namespace, relative to where ever you placed this class in your project directory.  So, say your new class is in a folder labeled "layouts" in your "src" directory, then in your Application tag in your main MXML file you would add a namespace for that folder:

```
xmlns:layouts="layouts.*"
```

and then your markup would look something like:

```
<layouts:MyNewLayoutClass .../>
```

Note: The name you use for the namespace does not necessarily have to match to the name of the folder.